# What is the best way of combining &key and &rest in a lisp macro's lambda list?

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I implemented [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap's_algorithm) using a macro. It's working OK, but I would like to tweak it so it will generate anaphoric or non-anaphoric code on demand. In other words, I would like to have the macro either make an internal copy of the sequence it will permutate or work on a sequence available outside the macro.

My utterly unsatisfactory, downright embarrassing code is:

```
;; Anaphoric version
;; To make it non-anaphoric, substitute (,var (copy-seq ,vec)) for (,var ,vec)
(defmacro run-permutations (var vec &rest body)
 "Executes body for all permutations of vec, which is stored in variable var"
  `(let ((,var ,vec))
     (labels ((generate (&optional (n (length ,var)))
       (if (= n 1)
         (progn ,@body)
        (progn 
           (loop for i from 0 below (1- n)
                 do (progn 
                      (generate (1- n))
                      (rotatef (aref ,var (if (evenp n) i 0))
                               (aref ,var (1- n)))))
           (generate (1- n))))))
      (generate))))

? (run-permutations v "123" (pprint v))
"123"
"213"
"312"
"132"
"231"
"321"
?
```

I would like to write something that worked like this...

```
? (setf v "123")
? (run-permutations :anaphoric t v "123" (...do stuff...))
? v
"321"

? (setf v "123")
? (run-permutations v "123" (...do stuff...))
? v
"123"
```

...but I haven't found a satisfactory combination of `&rest` and `&key` or any other approach for writing the lambda list.

So my question is: is there a way of accomplishing that, preferably without writing more code to parse the macro's lambda list? Or is there another, more or less standard (and presumably more elegant) solution out there? I strongly suspect the latter.

Your input is much appreciated. As always, any other comments on the code are appreciated as well.

**UPDATE**

Brilliant! I opted to use a `gensym` for `n` because `body` is called from within the recursion and I can't see how it could be called from elsewhere—at least not without rewriting everything.

I've also added another feature and a minor optimization. In case you're curious, the updated version is:

```
(defmacro do-permutations ((var vec &key anaphoric (len (length vec))) &body body)
  "Executes body for all permutations of vec, which is stored in variable var.
   KEYS:
     anaphoric: if defined, modifies var outside the macro, preserves it otherwise
     len: number of items that will be permuted, default is the full vector"
  (let ((n (gensym)))
  `(let ((,var ,(if anaphoric vec `(copy-seq ,vec))))
     (labels ((generate (&optional (,n ,len))
                (if (= ,n 1)
                    (progn ,@body)
                  (let ((n-1 (1- ,n)))
                    (loop for i from 0 below n-1
                          do (progn
                               (generate n-1)
                               (rotatef (aref ,var (if (evenp ,n) i 0))
                                        (aref ,var n-1))))
                    (generate n-1)))))
       (generate)))))
```

Finally, I tried to remove the`progn` after `do` but it didn't work because 2 expressions have to be evaluated at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indent your code correctly:

```
(defmacro run-permutations (var vec &rest body)
  "Executes body for all permutations of vec, which is stored in variable var"
  `(let ((,var ,vec))
     (labels ((generate (&optional (n (length ,var)))
                (if (= n 1)
                    (progn ,@body)
                  (progn 
                    (loop for i from 0 below (1- n)
                          do (progn 
                               (generate (1- n))
                               (rotatef (aref ,var (if (evenp n) i 0))
                                        (aref ,var (1- n)))))
                    (generate (1- n))))))
       (generate))))
```

Use something like:

```
(do-permutations (v "123" :anaphoric t)
  (some)
  (stuff))
```

with a macro:

```
(defmacro do-permutations ((var vec &key anaphoric) &body body)
  ...)
```

other names: `doing-permutations`, `with-permutations`, ...

Note also that the body can be declared with `&body`, instead of `&rest`. The semantics is the same, but one expect it to be indented differently. `&body` signals that a list of Lisp forms follows.

You also don't need a `progn` in a `loop`after `do`.

The `body` sees the variable `n`. You may think of another place for the body...

Comment: Do you know reference for correct indentation in lisp? I've been using emacs' default formatting and would be interested in an alternative.

Comment: @JonChesterfield: see here: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30788/why-does-emacs-indent-my-lisp-loop-construct-weirdly